# Compiling live555 and ffmpeg with Xcode 5

Tags: ios, compiler-construction, ffmpeg, live555

In my current project we need to use both live555 and ffmpeg libraries in the same project. We are able to build and run sample for both projects without issues, but when merging both projects into the project the following compiler errors were encountered:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "av_free_packet(AVPacket*)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient readFFmpegAudioFrameAndDecode] in MyRtspClient.o
  "av_read_frame(AVFormatContext*, AVPacket*)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient readFFmpegAudioFrameAndDecode] in MyRtspClient.o
  "av_strerror(int, char*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient readFFmpegAudioFrameAndDecode] in MyRtspClient.o
  "av_dict_set(AVDictionary**, char const*, char const*, int)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "av_init_packet(AVPacket*)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient readFFmpegAudioFrameAndDecode] in MyRtspClient.o
  "avcodec_register_all()", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "av_register_all()", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "av_log_set_level(int)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "av_log(void*, int, char const*, ...)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "avformat_alloc_context()", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "avformat_network_deinit()", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient destroyFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "avformat_open_input(AVFormatContext**, char const*, AVInputFormat*, AVDictionary**)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "avformat_find_stream_info(AVFormatContext*, AVDictionary**)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "av_find_best_stream(AVFormatContext*, AVMediaType, int, int, AVCodec**, int)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "av_dump_format(AVFormatContext*, int, char const*, int)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "avcodec_open2(AVCodecContext*, AVCodec const*, AVDictionary**)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "avformat_network_init()", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "av_dict_free(AVDictionary**)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
  "avcodec_find_decoder(AVCodecID)", referenced from:
      -[MyRtspClient initFFmpegAudioStream] in MyRtspClient.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I should have included all the required files so I am a bit dumbfounded by this, any suggestion is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can combine them quite successfully. I find the best way is to create a workspace,
merging the ffmpeg and the live555 libraries.

here's an example.[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try again, maybe it's something silly I did when merging. Just to be sure, have you tried and see if this works on Xcode 5.0.x?

Comment: Still getting the same error msgs, if your project is a simple merge of live555 & ffmpeg, is it possible to upload it somewhere for me to download and try? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you contact me directly, or via our Facebook page and maybe we can come up with something https://www.facebook.com/groups/mooncatventures/

Comment: Thanks, I've asked to join your FB group